# Who discovered first that the Moon does not have its own light?

Tags: science, astronomy

Who (and when) discovered first that the Moon does not have its own light?

Comment: do you have any idea what time period you're looking at? maybe renaissance era or earlier?

Comment: probably the first person to witness a lunar eclipse.

Comment: I am normally the first to agree that a lot of concepts are pre-historic, but I'm not so sure about this one.

Comment: @jwenting, It is like saying anyone who saw apple falling knew about earth's gravity.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at [History of Science SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @jwenting To an observer without knowledge of celestial mechanics, an eclipse looks like a mysterious dark body passing in front of the bright Moon.

Comment: Who was the first person to have a scientific understanding of "light"? My guess is that if you can discover that, it will give us a clue. [The debate across the ages was as to whether light was composed of particles or waves](http://www.timaras.com/science/light1.html). My guess, re. the moon, is that it dates from at least as far back as the ancient Greeks - possibly the Babylonians. But how about the Chinese?

Comment: I have an older source than the accepted answer but the question is protected :-(

Comment: "renaissance era or earlier"? Don't you expect that Ptolemy knew it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[image]
[Anaxagoras (500 BCE–428 BCE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaxagoras):

> Anaxagoras brought philosophy and the spirit of scientific inquiry from Ionia to Athens. His observations of the celestial bodies and the fall of meteorites led him to form new theories of the universal order. He attempted to give a scientific account of eclipses, meteors, rainbows, and the sun, which he described as a mass of blazing metal, larger than the Peloponnese. **He was the first to explain that the moon shines due to reflected light from the sun.** He also said that the moon had mountains and believed that it was inhabited. The heavenly bodies, he asserted, were masses of stone torn from the earth and ignited by rapid rotation. He explained that, though both sun and the stars were fiery stones, we do not feel the heat of the stars because of their enormous distance from earth. He thought that the earth is flat and floats supported by 'strong' air under it and disturbances in this air sometimes causes earthquakes.

*Cited source: Burnet J. (1892) Early Greek Philosophy A. & C. Black, London*

[SEP's page on Anaxagoras has this note](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/anaxagoras/#SciAnaCos):

> The sun is a mass of fiery metal, and the moon is an earthy lump (with no light of its own).

A [University of St. Andrews biography](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Anaxagoras.html) of the man has this to say:

> In about 450 BC Anaxagoras was imprisoned for claiming that the Sun was not a god and that the Moon reflected the Sun's light. This seems to have been instigated by opponents of Pericles. Russell in [*B Russell, History of Western Philosophy (London, 1961), 79-81.*] writes:-
>
> > *The citizens of Athens ... passed a law permitting impeachment of those who did not practice religion and taught theories about 'the things on high'. Under this law they persecuted Anaxagoras, who was accused of teaching that the sun was a red-hot stone and the moon was earth.*

> Anaxagoras proposed that the moon shines by reflected light from the "red-hot stone" which was the sun, the first such recorded claim. Showing great genius he was also then able to take the next step and become the first to explain correctly the reason for eclipses of the sun and moon.

His contributions are also discussed in a biographical page in [about.com's astronomy portal](http://space.about.com/od/astronomerbiographies/a/anaxagorasbio.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer coleopterist. I will wait some more time if someone can point to discovery more ancient than this before accepting your answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wasn't the first one.

Comment: Anaxagoras may have been the first one to propose this, but who was the first one to confirm that the moon does not produce its own light?

Comment: Re: "*He was first to explain that...*" — Do we know how he explained it?

Comment: How about the Chinese?